# No texture after baking process with mixed rgb

Tags: node-editor, texture-baking

I have an image texture that's connected to a mixed RGB(Multiply mode) and then a bsdf And after the bake I only got the color and no textures, When I removed the mixed RGB it works again, Do I have to change the color of the texture instead?

Answer (score 0):

It works with Mix  RGB node also.

Make sure that before you press the bake button the image texture node you want to bake on is selected.

Check your node setup also, the Color Ramp input is feeded by the vector displacement output, while it should get the Fac or color output of the Magic Texture.

[image]

Comment: I have selected the texture that I need to bake but it still doesn't work, My mixRGB's factor is on max, maybe that's the cause?

Comment: It should work even with the Fac at 1.0. Maybe you could upload your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, Yeah sure, Here's the file

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7PNYLpJo" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7PNYLpJo/)

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Tried connecting the color ramp with the magic fac and the color, It still only print the color, No texture, Could be something to do with the depth I set, It's at 0, But I want the checker pattern, I might need to use a tons of math nodes.

Comment: Edit: it was not the depth problem, So that's good, Still have the texture problem though.